# How can I get hold of the Composer object?

Tags: composer

I'm trying to get the file location of something in an installed package.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714809/get-filesystem-path-of-installed-composer-package says I can get that from the Composer object.

But in Drupal, how do I get the Composer object?

Comment: The comments in the linked question contain the answer - that object is available to Composer plugins/scripts/installers, not in the application. There are other answers with alternatives though

Answer (score 1):

Usually, I'm doing this using ReflectionClass.

Take this example: to load the `cacert file` which comes inside one of composer packages:

- First, locate **any** class in that package using ReflectionClass.
- Secondly, get the package path using `dirname` bypassing the file name.

Code example:

```
// Load certificate file.
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass(\GSRequest::class);
$packagePath = dirname($reflection->getFileName());
$gsRequest::setCAFile(realpath($packagePath . '/cacert.pem'));
```